# Recording sfx during sprinkle (rain)

Tags: waterproof

What measure should you take to protect your mic if you are interested in catching sound in the rain?  The pop filter is all I have and I am not venturing out into the moisture with only that thing.  What do you guys do?  Zeppelin?  Rycote? Umbrella?

Answer (score 8):

Record with a zepplin wrapped in a [Rainman](http://www.remoteaudio.com/rainman/)

Answer (score 2):

Putting the mic under a carport or porch can help protect it and still capture rain sounds.  I usually use a full rycote setup (blimp and furry) and find that you can also stick the mic out in the middle of rain for some time without issue.  Keep in mind that if the mic is directly in the rain, the sound of rain drops on the mic might ruin your recording.  You'll want to keep a close eye on your gear when you are recording in or around rain.  Check your rycote often, when it becomes very wet, it is time to pull the get in and go back inside.  Let your furry air dry, don't try to put it in a clothes dryer.  Also, wear boot and a good rain jacket, it sucks being wet and cold when you are trying to record sounds.

Samples of some rain the I recorded with my Neumann RSM191 are here:

http://chuckrussomfx.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2&products_id=8

Answer (score 1):

Put the gear in a garage or under a carport, well outside the rain.